# How do you bind FontFamily to custom font in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, mvvm, fonts

I am working on a Silverlight 4 application which will be used as a image creator/editor. The user is shown a blank canvas from where he can add images and text in layers (similar to Photoshop) and then flatten it all and save the resulting image.

When the user adds text he needs to be able to change the font e.g. Arial, Chiller etc. I have created a font picker which consists of a combobox populated with TextBlocks that represent each of the Silverlight default fonts.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="fontBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Grid.Row="0">
   <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding=?}" FontFamily="{Binding=?}" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

My problem is that I need to use custom fonts to populate the combobox and as I am using the MVVM design pattern it all has to be done in code. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use a converter

FontFamily="{Binding SomeProperty, Converter={StaticResource FontConverter}}"

then create a converter that will return a FontFamily